# Best emailing approach with template emails

Tags: php, email

We are creating a project with lots of different mail templates in it. There are different messages for different purposes and we are trying to make the coding easy and understandable for the future.

By the way we have different transport classes like e-mail, sms, twitter vs...

Now we are doing this but I dont know if there is a better solution.

We have a class called

```
H2B_Message_Container_Mail_About_Blablabla
```

it has 4 methods;

```
interface H2B_Message_Mail_Interface
{
    public function setName($name);
    public function setValue($key, $value);
    public function getMailBody();
    public function getMailSubject();
}
```

and in the mail body there are various variables as expected.

before we send the mail, we get the variable values from the database with JSON format and decode it.

Then we send it like;

```
$mail = new H2B_Message_Mail();
$mail->setTemplate($newTemplate);
$mail->send();
```

The question is; is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: well what do you feel could be improved with your current implementation? Personally i would have proanly used single meaasging class and then had setters to configure the transport type but i dont think that offers any clear advantage over what youve described.

Answer (score 1):

1. The method `send` is not in your interface
2. The transport type should be configurable I think.

Your interface looks like `Zend_Mail`. This is a somewhat simple interface which might be good enough for you. But if you want to send e-mails with embedded images it is better to further split your interfaces. Better you just use `Swiftmailer`, according to many the best Php Mailer.

Comment: I dont have problem with mailing but storing the templates and working with them. Also we dont want to send image just writings. By the way the code above is not the actual code, I simplified you to understand easyly.